# Snapping points of a roughly spherical mesh exactly onto a sphere

Tags: modeling

I have a mesh whose points ought to lie on a sphere.  They don't, but are roughly close.  Is there a convenient way to nudge them all along their radii to "snap" each to some fixed R?

I've been nudging each vertex by hand, for a simple demo model, but this isn't practical when I get to more elaborate cases.  I tries extrude-scaling the mesh toward the center point, then using a boolean intersection with a sphere, but that cut off all the intricate surface topology, leaving hollow shapes like oddly tapered cookie cutters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## To sphere:

You could try <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*>[To Sphere](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/to_sphere.html#to-sphere)*:

From the [wiki](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/to_sphere.html#to-sphere):

> The *To Sphere* transformation will give the selection spherical qualities.

Example:

[image]

## Shrinkwrap:

Or using the *[Shrinkwrap](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html#shrinkwrap-modifier)* modifier to shrink your mesh to a sphere object.

From the [wiki](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html#shrinkwrap-modifier):

> The *Shrinkwrap* modifier allows an object to “shrink” to the surface of another object. It moves each vertex of the object being modified to the closest position on the surface of the given mesh (using one of the three methods available).

You could add a shrinkwrap modifier to your mesh and set the *Target* to a sphere:

[image]

Comment: One advantage of shrinkwrap over to sphere is that you get to decide exactly where the new sphere shaped object is and how big it is (the same as your target). With to sphere, the new object placement is somewhat random.

Comment: Hah, forgot about "To Sphere" due to lack of use the last few years. Saw it when I first learned Blender.  But Shrinkwrap looks great, since it handles non-spheres also.